# select hex(md5("anything"))%4; Why is this always zero?

Tags: mysql

Why is this always zero in mysql???

```
select hex(md5("anything"))%4;
```

I have tried replacing "anything" with anything but it's always zero.

Expect to have 0,1,2 or 3 as value but it's not showing as shown.

I would like to have (md5sum("anything") % 4). How is this possible?

**Is this the best answer / solution to what I need? Does not feel right**

```
SELECT CONV(SUBSTRING(md5('anything0-10'), 1, 15), 16, 10)%4096;
```

Comment: `hex(md5("anything"))` returns you a string and not a number. Not entirely sure what happens next that results in 0, but this is the core of your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HEX()` returns a string of hexadecimal digits, not a number.

```
mysql> select hex(md5("anything"));
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| hex(md5("anything"))                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 6630653136366463333464313464366332323866666163353736633961343363 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`HEX(md5('anything'))` returns all decimal digits. This is NOT a coincidence. MySQL's MD5() function already returns a hex-encoded string (your calling HEX() on it is redundant). Therefore it only returns characters 0-9 and a-f:

```
mysql> select md5('anything');
+----------------------------------+
| md5('anything')                  |
+----------------------------------+
| f0e166dc34d14d6c228ffac576c9a43c |
+----------------------------------+
```

When you call HEX() on this string, it returns only hex values 30-39 and 61-66, encoding the ascii values of 0-9 and a-f.

This is all to explain why the long string contains only decimal digits.

When you use that string in an expression with `% 4`, MySQL interprets the string in a numeric context. MySQL will try to evaluate the numeric value of the string, which means reading the leading decimal digits from the string.

We can also coerce the string to a numeric context with `+0`:

```
mysql> select hex(md5('anything'))+0;
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| hex(md5('anything'))+0                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 6630653136366463000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The 64-digit number is larger than MySQL integer types can represent, so the numeric coercion must convert it to a DOUBLE value. This data type is 8 bytes, which is still not enough to represent a 64-digit number. So it rounds the value and ignores the lower digits, converting them to zeroes.

Naturally, a number ending with a bunch of zeroes is evenly divisible by 4, so modulus expression is bound to return 0.

---

> I would like to have (md5sum("anything") % 4). How is this possible?

```
mysql> select conv(right(md5('anything'), 1), 16, 10) % 4 as mod4;
+------+
| mod4 |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. i would like to have (md5sum("anything") % 4). How is this possible?

Comment: Very nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be as follows:

- `hex(md5("anything"))` returns a STRING,
- `%` performs implicit cast to DOUBLE,
- casting drops low bits
- after droping two low bits, every number is a multiply of 4

For the `%4` operation only the last hex digit is relevant, so you could:

- get the last hex digit from the MD5 sum
- convert it to base 10
- perform the %4 operation

```
SELECT CONV(SUBSTRING(md5('anything'), -1), 16, 10)%4;
```

Comment: i would like to have (md5sum("anything") % 4). How is this possible?